# sql query with condition on date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a little simple problem. I want to perform a query on a Mysql table to select posts posted after a certain date but I don't manage to get it working by setting that date as a PHP variable.

The following query doesn't return anything:

```
$reqsql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_date <= " . $from_date;
```

The "post_date" field is set as a datetime. I have tried everything for the $from_date PHP variable format:

```
$from_date = date();
$from_date = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
$from_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$from_date = strtodate("now");
```

None of these work...

But it works fine if I put a basic Mysql date like:

```
$reqsql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_date <= NOW()";
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Your SQL query is malformed. You should always output errors (eg: `mysql_error()` or similar) in dev mode so you know what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably only need to wrap `$from_date` in single quotes.

```
$reqsql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_date <= '" . $from_date ."'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the date between quotes:

```
$reqsql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_date <= '" . $from_date . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the date like any other string in your query:

```
$reqsql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_date <= '" . $from_date . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the date from PHP in UNIX-time format using `time()` and then run [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) on it in the SQL query.